# Script(?) to copy website text and automatically email it daily

Tags: email, script, website, copy-paste

Is there a way to automatically copy text from a website and email it to me daily?

The scenario is this: my son’s teachers post his daily homework on a website. Each class has its own page. Rather than me visiting 7 pages every day (1 for each class) and manually copy/pasting the assignments into a master assignment document, I’d like to automate the process and have it emailed to me, so that if I’m working or in a meeting, I can just receive an email containing all the assignments copied from the different pages and don’t have to take the time to do manually do this every day.

Is this even possible? If so, please point me in the right direction.

I use a Windows 7 laptop and have Chrome, IE, etc. My email is gmail, yahoo, or Outlook (work-based Exchange server). The website on which the homework is posted does not require any logins and does not have any option to subscribe. My skill level is zero experience, but I'm willing to learn.

Comment: Some sites offer a RSS feed - perhaps that is also the case for the site you are referring to? Then you could either use a RSS reader or something like [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com) to be notified via E-Mail.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no RSS option on the homework site, nor any other way to subscribe to updates. Thank you for the suggestion, though!

Comment: Just to understand your requirement correctly: Would it suffice to trigger the check manually or should it be some kind of "check every x minutes/hours"?

Comment: If it could check once every day, maybe after school at 4 pm. In a perfect world, I would like it to just show up in my email without me having to do anything.

Comment: Do you have a machine that is always on or switched on every day at 4 pm?

Comment: Yes. It has Windows 7 and access to email via gmail/yahoo/Outlook and access to web via IE/Chrome/Firefox.

Comment: @Tyson You write "You could script this pretty easily on any linux computer that is always on, windows there is no easy way"  <--- well that's obviously not true.  You can use a 3rd party command written only for windows like sendemail, or you could use ports of *nix commands.. And even before powershell, there is and was vbscript which is old but probably more powerful than bash! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21973581/send-email-through-vbs-script  and there's jscript (quite oldold).. so it has been possible for years.

Comment: @barlop thanks I delete that statement... I never had luck with things like this in windows but do it frequently elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

I have used mention.com and google alerts for this sort of thing.  I recommend setting them both up to see which one gives you good, fine-tuned results.  They're both free.

Make a filter so all the resulting emails go into a particular folder.

https://en.mention.com/

https://www.google.com/alerts

Answer (score -1):

Yes this is possible.  Powershell and VBScript are built into Windows and can accomplish this task.  In Powershell you would use the `wget` command and the `send-mailmessage` command.

Comment: I don't think this fully answers the question.

Comment: @BloodPhilia It *fully* answers his question,"Is this even possible? If so, please point me in the right direction"